# Safely split/paginate an HTML String with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, regex, string

I have rendered one of my controls into a string. I want to safely split the html string. I don't want any hanging html tags. I am working on a pagination control adapter.

How can I split my string, around less than a set number of chars) safely taking HTML into account?

Comment: It would likely be a lot easier to do the pagination before you render the control to a string. Any particular reason you need to do it after you've rendered it as a string?

Comment: Its from a CMS, its already as HTML string. Some are done as ASP.NET Web Forms, others are just HTML content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack). You can use it to parse and manipulate the html in your string without having to resort to regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a nice way to show the HTML code you should try [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/).
I did not use it with a limitation on the number of charecters per line, but I think HTML Tidy [wrap](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html#wrap) option might get you close to your target.